# Desactivar option select de formulario php

Tags: php

tengo esta parte del código de un formulario de reservas:

```
   <select name="time" required>
                              <option value="">Reservar hora</option>
                                 <option value="9:00-10:00">09:00 - 10:00</option>
                                <option value="10:15-11:15">10:15 - 11:15</option>
                                <option value="11:30-12:30">11:30 - 12:30</option>
                                <option value="12:45-13:45">12:45 - 13:45</option>
                                <option value="13:00-14:00">14:00 - 15:00</option>
                                <option value="14:00-15:00">15:15 - 16:15</option>
                                <option value="16:30-17:30">16:30 - 17:30</option>
                                <option value="17:45-18:45">17:45 - 18:45</option>
                            </select>
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo podría desactivar por ejemplo la opción  16:30 - 17:30?
De manera que porque ese horario esta ocupado ya por un cliente, el usuario no pueda enviar el formulario.
Gracias y un saludo

Solución
Gracias por la información y enlace y he encontrado:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup
He incluido el elemento optgroup y ahi pongo la fecha de reserva y el formulario no se puede enviar.

```
<select name="time" required>
                                <option value="">Reservar hora</option>
                            <option value="16:30-17:30">16:30 - 17:30</option>
                            <optgroup label="Reservada: 22/5 17:45 - 18:45">
                                <option value="">17:45 - 18:45</option>
                                 <option value="19:00-20:00">19:00 - 20:00</option>
                            </select>
```

Es lo que estaba buscando, esa día y hora no se puede enviar.
Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Usa el [atributo disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) en el `option` necesario. Esto lo puedes controlar por programación con PHP.

Comment: Pero `optgroup` no es para desactivar una opción, sino para crear grupos de opciones y lo que pones ahí dentro sería como el título de ese grupo. Si se trata de desactivar una o más de las opciones tienes que usar `disabled`, como te comenta @aeportugal. Además, usar `optgroup` no te servirá en contextos dinámicos donde el `option` podría ser activado si se libera.

Comment: Las respuesta deben ir como respuesta, se que te dijeron que no lo era en un comentario pero esa persona cometió un error.

Comment: Lo que había puesto no tenia el mismo formato de la edición que hizo, no daba a entender que lo tenia resuelto. Al final si hubiese editado esa respuesta y le colocase que de esa forma había solventado su problema no habría confusión o con solo marcarla como aceptada habría bastado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responderé solo porque has generado una confusión en el asunto.

Para desactivar un `option` basta con agregar el atributo `disabled` y nada más

```
<option value="16:30-17:30" disabled>16:30 - 17:30</option>
```

Ejemplo

```html
<select name="time" required>
    <option value="">Reservar hora</option>
    <option value="9:00-10:00">09:00 - 10:00</option>
    <option value="10:15-11:15">10:15 - 11:15</option>
    <option value="11:30-12:30">11:30 - 12:30</option>
    <option value="12:45-13:45">12:45 - 13:45</option>
    <option value="13:00-14:00">14:00 - 15:00</option>
    <option value="14:00-15:00">15:15 - 16:15</option>
    <option value="16:30-17:30" disabled>16:30 - 17:30</option>
    <option value="17:45-18:45">17:45 - 18:45</option>
</select>
```

El `optgroup` es para agrupar opciones, y claro como se agrega un titulo no seleccionable a dicha agrupación tu piensas que está desactivado.

Por ejemplo podríamos agrupas los horarios en `Mañana` y `Tarde`

```html
<select name="time" required>
  <option disabled selected>Reservar hora</option>
  <optgroup label="Mañana"> 
    <option value="9:00-10:00">09:00 - 10:00</option>
    <option value="10:15-11:15">10:15 - 11:15</option>
    <option value="11:30-12:30">11:30 - 12:30</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Tarde"> 
    <option value="12:45-13:45">12:45 - 13:45</option>
    <option value="13:00-14:00">14:00 - 15:00</option>
    <option value="14:00-15:00">15:15 - 16:15</option>
    <option value="16:30-17:30" disabled>16:30 - 17:30</option>
    <option value="17:45-18:45">17:45 - 18:45</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Si te fijas la primera opción también le he colocado `disabled`, habitualmente se hace esto con el `option` que funciona de titulo del select ya que este no cuenta con `placeholder` como los `input`

Comment: Silnceramente cuando puse en  primera instancia el elemento optgroup, no se algo me decía que no era optimo, pero al estar la opción inactiva me valía. No obstante te agradezco Yussef tus aclaraciones y la puesta en escena del código. Se ve mucho más profesional.